# How to fix/investigate Windows Defender detecting malware in the VSS snapshots for Firefox cached files?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, malware, windows-7-backup, vss

**Update**: Seems solved as of March 4.

- I was able to remove the bypass (path exclusion in Defender) and perform backups without malware detection, even after re-accessing the site linked in the original question.
- Mozilla has closed the [related bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1872395), with the reason they believe it's a false positive, which is also my *opinion*.
- Microsoft [doesn't seem to have posted any authoritative information](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/search/search?SearchTerm=%22phish!pz%22&tab=&status=all&advFil=&IsSuggestedTerm=false&isFilterExpanded=undefined&CurrentScope.ForumName=&CurrentScope.Filter=&ContentTypeScope=QnA,Discussion,Article,MicrosoftSupport&page=1&sort=Relevance&dir=Desc) about updating their malware signatures. There are many pre-formatted suggestions from their independent advisors (which don't seem to consider false positive can exist).

---

**Original post**

Late December Windows 10 backup (old Windows 7 version) started to fail at the VSS snapshot creation step, because Defender reports `HTML/Phish!pz` in the cache folder of Firefox.

For example accessing [https://www.math.wustl.edu/~freiwald/309fibonacci.pdf](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Efreiwald/309fibonacci.pdf) systematically creates a cache entry `1C7517ACB77A3721AE2BFD9CB54A965ABF7DC7FC` which is identified as containing a malware in the snapshot.

[image]

(malware `HTML/Phish!pz` in `\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy32\Users\*\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\cache2\entries` folder)

It seems to be a problem with Defender, not with Firefox or Backup. [ESET online scanner](https://www.eset.com/int/home/online-scanner/) doesn't see a malware. Possibly a false positive, not yet confirmed by Microsoft.

---

**My questions**

- Why Defender doesn't see the infection when the file is created in the cache folder, but only when Backup use the copy in the shadow volume?
- Is there a logical method to investigate further this problem, confirming the malware is a real one?

Optionally: Does it exist a better description of the malware HTML/Phish!pz than [MS description](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=PWS:HTML/Phish.PZ&threatId=-2147255708) which doesn't describe the action mode.

---

**Additional details**

- In the tests I made, Defender sees this malware signature only in shadow volume copies, and specifically in Firefox cache folder.
- Defender doesn't see a threat on the original cache entry.
- After creating a symbolic link to access the shadow volume, and scanning the snapshot, Defender doesn't see any malware.
- This happens regardless of the type of scan (on-the-fly, full scan, offline scan).
- Deleting the snapshots doesn't help as a new snapshot with the same problem is created at the next backup.

---

**Interim workaround**

A possible workaround is to exclude `cache2` folder **in the snapshot** from Defender scope, with a generic path. As snapshots are not in usual namespace, the exclusion cannot be added with Defender UI, Powershell must be used:

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy*\Users\*\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\cache2.
```

Thanks to [@hardworker](https://superuser.com/a/1826065/89738) for mentioning the PS command. Don't forget to [remove this exclusion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/remove-mppreference?view=windowsserver2022-ps) when it's no longer required. The original `cache2` in the user profile is still scanned, so it's deemed safe. However a real malware file could be intentionally added to this unmonitored folder after the snapshot creation, so if this snapshot is to be restored for any reason, it's advisable to not restore this specific `cache2` path.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP stated the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is a false positive detection by Windows Defender. The "virus signature" is created when Windows 10 backup (old Windows 7 version) builds the VSS image with the Firefox cache2 folder. In the last week of Dec 2023, Defender malware patterns started "detecting" Trojan:HTML/Phish!pz in the resulting VSS image.
Microsoft needs to fix this false positive.

My workaround is to add a Windows Defender EXCLUSION for the VSS image.
The GUI will not allow the VSS path to be entered so it must be added with the Powershell commandlet "Add-MpPreference". This exclusion I use excludes all VSS images on the basis that I normally scan the full file system. You can make the path more specific if you want to exclude only the Firefox cache2.
Here is the command

```
PS C:\> Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy*\"
```

Backups complete normally again after the exclusion is applied.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a good workaround until the solution. What makes you think this is a false positive?

Comment: The biggest issue with this is that you're forcibly whitelisting a large and rather important section of storage that has been known to store viral loads. Microsoft fixing their signatures is better, but can you whitelist a more focused section of storage to narrow the chance this could result in backing up viral loads for later re-infection?

Comment: likely a false positive because my nightly backup has been running for years with no issue. After MS signature updates in Dec. 2023 this issue started. I also tried to submit for analysis but I cannot find an easy method to archive/submit the VSS content. Deep scanning the source folders ( *\AppData\Local\Mozilla\* ) with Defender does not detect any malware. Yes, this could be something injecting malware into the VSS folders. It is unlikely that EVERYONE who uses "Windows 10 backup (old Windows 7 version)" to backup this Firefoxfolder would have the SAME malware!

Comment: I was able to remove the exclusion path, it seems MS has silently updated their malware, signatures. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote this answer in response to the request to edit. I have the same issue. I do not have a solution. I am sharing my unsuccessful attempts to eliminate the creation of an affected shadow file.  Protection history report:

> Detected: Trojan:HTML/Phish!pz   Status: Failed   Details: This
> program is dangerous and executes commands from an attacker.
> Affected items file:
> \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy97\Users\Reynold\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jfrgi35u.default-release\cache2\entries\02907D376A10490DAA61D7FF40D1C11C9258A268

The command
**vssadmin list shadows**
showed all shadow files on all 6 drives including the affected no. 97 on the `C:` drive.
The command
**vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=401MB**
eliminated the file, as shown by the command
**vssadmin list shadows /for=C:**
Which reported no items found on C:.

At this point the C: drive is apparently clear of shadow files. Now I run a backup which goes onto the E: drive. The backup software is the Backup and Restore Utility (Windows 7). My OS is Windows 10. The first step of this backup utility is to create a shadow file. As it is being created it includes or absorbs the file *Trojan:HTML/Phish!pz*. Before the backup is completed, the virus is detected and the backup is aborted. Defender Protection History shows the existence of the file, same filepath, with a new number of the shadow copy.
I have repeatedly run full online scans, custom scans on C:, and offline scans. They do not solve the issue, which has existed for about 10 days now.

Additional information 1/17/2023. I've had 2 long chat sessions with Microsoft. They say it is an actual threat, not a false positive. None of their prescribed steps have eliminated it. The procedure by Thurion worked for me. I did a manual backup, and an automatic backup after that -- both successful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the info which is helpful. I'm inclined to think this is a false positive, or a threat exists but is not reported correctly (the threat would manipulate VSS service in order to store an infection in the snapshot, which would be active when restoring the snapshot -- quite far-fetched). 10 days also correct for me, might be a problem with MS threat definitions.

Answer (score 1):

**This is more a workaround than a solution**

You can delete only the volume shadow copy that contains the malicious file:

```
vssadmin list shadows /for=c:
vssadmin delete shadows /shadow="shadowID"

# for example:
vssadmin delete shadows /shadow="{7d910f50-b963-48d5-92ef-ca546ba32cc2}"
```

In my case I got the exact same problem as you did: The Firefox cache.
Here's what I did:

1. Removed the shadow copy by using the commands above
2. Set Firefox to delete the cache upon closing. This can be found in Settings -> Privacy & Security -> History
3. Closed Firefox
4. Made sure the `cache2` directory is not present in my profile. `%localappdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`
5. Ran the backup again

This might be helpful if you run the backup manually as I do but when it runs automatically this won't help much unfortunately.

I also submitted a report to Microsoft at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission/ and I hope they manage to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but I'd spent too much time on what will hopefully get resolved by MS/Mozilla sorting out what appears to be a false positive with Firefox. (MS probably not - see below)

I had exactly the same symptoms as reported - my fixes were:

1. replace Defender with Sophos which was my security package of choice when Defender was not a good solution and I still have a licence for the other boxes in the house.
2. install Veeam Community Edition (free and fine for a single box)

Now this isn't a full test. I didn't fully verify whether Veeam would work with Defender and firefox (no reason to think it would), nor whether Sophos alone would work:

1. Sophos appeared to get bogged down at ~97% when working with windows 7 backup - so I terminated the backup and installed Veeam as well - but that might me getting impatient.
2. Haven't disabled Sophos to verify if Defender will work with Veeam, but I would doubt it.

The Veeam backup it also got bogged down slightly in the System Image phase (96-99%) but ran to completion and the overnight update also ran without issue.

It may of course be that MS has finally given up on it.  They deprecated it in 1709. Annoying, because until this it did actually work - least it did last time I had to use it.

[MS feature deprecation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features#:%7E:text=1709-,System%20Image%20Backup,-(SIB)%20Solution)

> System Image Backup (SIB) Solution    This feature is also known as the Backup and Restore (Windows 7) legacy control panel. For full-disk backup solutions, look for a third-party product from another software publisher. You can also use OneDrive to sync data files with Microsoft 365.     1709

Comment: Of course if you think Veeam  is better than Defender why not. But if this is to eliminate a protection because it reports a threat it can't fix, and replace it by another which doesn't detect it, it's not logical. If the problem is not to receive an alert until MS fix a possible false positive, you can temporarily exclude the Firefox cache from Defender scope.

Comment: I think you mean Sophos rather than Veeam. I regard Sophos/Defender equally from an AV perspective

The move to Veeam was because:
* I only have to support my own box
* Win 7 backup wasn't deprecated when I set up the process 

Based on reports on Mozilla the consensus seems to point to issues with Defender as a false positive https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1872395

Could it be an APT buried in Firefox. Possibly but we're all getting the same trojan message. Seems unlikely because people with earlier versions of FF & Thunderbird are also getting the issue since ~Dec 26

Comment: I got it, thanks for the link, it's definitely one you could include in your answer as it may be updated with interesting elements from Mozilla. I added a workaround in my question, excluding the cache folder from Defender scope. I think this is the easiest solution so far.